# Grade Calculation Program: Array Out of Bounds

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've been working on this program for 20+ hours and I feel like I'm really close to finishing, but I cannot seem to fix my array out of bounds exception. I'll provide my whole code here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GradeCalcArryas { /*
                             * Logan Wegner The purpose is to calculate
                             * entered grades
                             */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); // first scanner for inputs
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in); // second scanner for string

    boolean done = false; // so an if statement can be inputted for the code
                            // to break back to the menu
    boolean quit = false;
    int choice = 0;
    final int MAX_STUDENTS = 200;

    //Array created to store the information entered for exams
    int[] examStats = new int[3]; 

    //Array created to store the information entered for quizzes
    int[] quizStats = new int[3];

    //Array created to store the information entered for homework
    int[] homeworkStats = new int[3]; 

    //Array created to store the student name information entered
    String[] studentNames = new String[MAX_STUDENTS]; 

    System.out.println("Welcome to GradeBook!");
    System.out.println("Please provide grade item details");

    System.out.print("Exams    (number, points, weight):");

    examStats[0] = s.nextInt(); // inputs exam number
    examStats[1] = s.nextInt(); // inputs exam points
    examStats[2] = s.nextInt(); // inputs exam weight

    System.out.print("Quizzes     (number, points, weight):");

    quizStats[0] = s.nextInt(); // inputs quiz number
    quizStats[1] = s.nextInt(); // inputs quiz points
    quizStats[2] = s.nextInt(); // inputs quiz weight

    System.out.print("Homework    (number, points, weight):");

    homeworkStats[0] = s.nextInt(); // inputs homework number
    homeworkStats[1] = s.nextInt(); // inputs homework points
    homeworkStats[2] = s.nextInt(); // inputs homework weight

    /*int numExams = examStats[0];
    int numQuizzes = quizStats[0];
    int numHW = homeworkStats[0];
    int tableLength = numExams + numQuizzes + numHW + 1;*/

    /*double[][] examScores = new double[MAX_STUDENTS][];
    double[][] quizScores = new double[MAX_STUDENTS][];
    double[][] hwScores = new double[MAX_STUDENTS][];*/

    //arrays for the average exam, quiz, homework, gradeAverage, and gradeWeightedAverage score of each student             
    double[] examAverage = new double[MAX_STUDENTS];
    double[] quizAverage = new double[MAX_STUDENTS];
    double[] hwAverage = new double[MAX_STUDENTS];
    double[] gradeAverage = new double[MAX_STUDENTS];

    // counters
    int numExams = 0;
    int numQuizzes = 0;
    int numHW = 0;

    // declare Double[] exams using length numExams
    double[] exams = new double[numExams];

    // declare Double[] quizzes using length numQuizzes
    double[] quizzes = new double[numQuizzes];

    // declare Double[] HW using length numHW
    double[] hw = new double[numHW];


    //Calculating percentage to multiply exam, quiz, and homework averages
    double examWeight = examStats[2]/100;
    double quizWeight = quizStats[2]/100;
    double hwWeight = homeworkStats[2]/100;




    System.out.println("--------------------");

    do {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("    1 Add student data");
        System.out.println("    2 Display student grades & statistics");
        System.out.println("    3 Plot grade distribution");
        System.out.println("    4 Quit");
        System.out.print("Your choice:");
        choice = s.nextInt(); /*
                             * Choice will determine what the next course of
                             * action will be with the program
                             */







            if (choice == 1) { // ADD STUDENT DATA
                System.out.println("Enter student data:");

                for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_STUDENTS; i++) { // iterate through 200
                                                            // times
                                                            // (MAX_STUDENTS) or
                                                            // break
                    System.out.print("Data>");
                    String dataentry = s1.nextLine(); // read inputed data

                    if (dataentry.equals("done")) { // if user inputs "done",
                                                    // break
                        break;
                    }

                    // ArrayList that holds all information (Name, Exams,
                    // Quizzes, Homework)
                    ArrayList<String> allInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

                    // tokenize using ":" delimiter, splitting up the name
                    // (firstsplit[0]) from the rest of the information
                    String[] firstsplit = dataentry.split(":");
                    studentNames[i] = firstsplit[0];

                    // add name to ArrayList allinfo
                    allInfo.add(firstsplit[0] + "\t");


                    // tokenize using " " delimiter, splitting up each score
                    String[] secondsplit = firstsplit[1].split(" ");


                    for (int k = 0; k < secondsplit.length; k++) { // iterates
                                                                    // through
                                                                    // Array
                                                                    // secondsplit

                        allInfo.add(secondsplit[k] + "\t"); // adds item at [k]
                                                            // to ArrayList
                                                            // allInfo

                        // if the first char in secondsplit[k] is "e" increment
                        // numExams
                        if (secondsplit[k].subSequence(0, 1).equals("e"))
                            numExams++;
                        // if the first char in secondsplit[k] is "q" increment
                        // numQuizzes
                        if (secondsplit[k].subSequence(0, 1).equals("q"))
                            numQuizzes++;
                        // if the first char in secondsplit[k] is "h" increment
                        // numHW
                        if (secondsplit[k].subSequence(0, 1).equals("h"))
                            numHW++;
                    }


                    // iterates through Array exams and adds values from allInfo
                    for (int k = 0; k < exams.length; k++) {
                        exams[k] = Double.parseDouble(allInfo.get(1 + k)
                                .substring(1));

                    }

                    // iterates through Array quizzes and adds values from
                    // allInfo
                    for (int k = 0; k < quizzes.length; k++) {
                        quizzes[k] = Double.parseDouble(allInfo.get(
                                1 + numExams + k).substring(1));

                    }

                    // iterates through Array hw and adds values from allInfo
                    for (int k = 0; k < hw.length; k++) {
                        hw[k] = Double.parseDouble(allInfo.get(
                                1 + numExams + numQuizzes + k).substring(1));

                    }

                    //Index counters for averages
                    int examIndex = 0;
                    int quizIndex = 0;
                    int hwIndex = 0;
                    int gradeAveragingIndex = 0;

                    //loop finding the gradeAverage
                    for(int index = 0; index < MAX_STUDENTS; index++){
                        examAverage[index] = ((exams[examIndex]) + (exams[examIndex+1]) + (exams[examIndex+2])) / (numExams);
                        quizAverage[index] = ((quizzes[quizIndex]) + (quizzes[quizIndex+1]) + (quizzes[quizIndex+2])) / (numQuizzes);
                        hwAverage[index] = ((hw[hwIndex]) + (hw[hwIndex+1]) + (hw[hwIndex+2])) / (numHW);
                        gradeAverage[index] = ((examAverage[gradeAveragingIndex] * examWeight) + (quizAverage[gradeAveragingIndex] * quizWeight) + (hwAverage[gradeAveragingIndex] * hwWeight) / numExams);

                        examIndex+=3;
                        quizIndex+=3;
                        hwIndex+=3;
                        gradeAveragingIndex++;

                    }
                }
            }

        //This choice is to display student grades & statistics in a table
        if (choice == 2) {

            System.out.println("Display student grades & statistics");

            //Formatting for the heading of my grade table
            System.out.printf("%-10s","Name");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
            System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
            System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
            System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Grade\n");

            //declaring index counters
            int studentNameIndex = 0;
            int examGradeIndex = 0;
            int quizGradeIndex = 0;
            int homeworkGradeIndex = 0;
            int gradeAverageIndex = 0;

            //for loop for the output of exams, quizzes, homework, and grade average
            for(int index = 0; index < studentNames.length; index++) {
                System.out.printf("%-10s",studentNames[studentNameIndex]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex+1]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex+2]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[quizGradeIndex]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[quizGradeIndex+1]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[quizGradeIndex+2]);
                System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[homeworkGradeIndex]);
                System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[homeworkGradeIndex+1]);
                System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[homeworkGradeIndex+2]);
                System.out.printf("%-5.1f",gradeAverage[gradeAverageIndex] + "\n");

                studentNameIndex++;
                examGradeIndex+=3;
                quizGradeIndex+=3;
                homeworkGradeIndex+=3;
                gradeAverageIndex++;
            }

        }

        if (choice == 3) {


        }

        if (choice == 4) {
            quit = true;
            System.out.println("Good bye!");
        }

    }while (quit == false);
}   
}
```

My out of bounds exception occurs here:

```
//loop finding the gradeAverage
                    for(int index = 0; index < MAX_STUDENTS; index++){
                        examAverage[index] = ((exams[examIndex]) + (exams[examIndex+1]) + (exams[examIndex+2])) / (numExams);
                        quizAverage[index] = ((quizzes[quizIndex]) + (quizzes[quizIndex+1]) + (quizzes[quizIndex+2])) / (numQuizzes);
                        hwAverage[index] = ((hw[hwIndex]) + (hw[hwIndex+1]) + (hw[hwIndex+2])) / (numHW);
                        gradeAverage[index] = ((examAverage[gradeAveragingIndex] * examWeight) + (quizAverage[gradeAveragingIndex] * quizWeight) + (hwAverage[gradeAveragingIndex] * hwWeight) / numExams);

                        examIndex+=3;
                        quizIndex+=3;
                        hwIndex+=3;
                        gradeAveragingIndex++;
}
```

My exception is either ArrayOutofBounds: 0 or ArrayOutofBounds: 3. It has something to do with my exam, quiz, and hw arrays. I've moved them around in my program and changed my numExams, numQuizzes, and numHW values, but it still gives me some trouble. I'd love some insight. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you have issue here:

```
int numExams = 0;
int numQuizzes = 0;
int numHW = 0;

// declare Double[] exams using length numExams
double[] exams = new double[numExams];

// declare Double[] quizzes using length numQuizzes
double[] quizzes = new double[numQuizzes];

// declare Double[] HW using length numHW
double[] hw = new double[numHW];
```

Your are declaring here arrays with size 0. If you have more issues - I was not checking.

Comment: that's what I originally thought as well, but if I place my double arrays in my choice1 where I origionally declared them then I can't use my exams, quizzes, and hw arrays in choice2 to get my averages and output the values.

Comment: You can. Just make out of condition: double[] exams; and then in codition: exams = new double[numExams];

Comment: Doing it that way still makes my exams array in choice2 not work.                                 `
    `for(int index = 0; index < studentNames.length; index++) {
        System.out.printf("%-10s",studentNames[studentNameIndex]);
        System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex]);
        System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex+1]);
        System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex+2]);` This is only part of my code, the whole thing was too long for me to output in the comments. By going the way you suggested these exam arrays do not work. Any solutions?

Comment: it is looking, that at any moment you are not sure, how many data you will have. So maybe don't declare exact size of these array, and give general number like this:
int numExams = 0;
    int numQuizzes = 0;
    int numHW = 0;

    // declare Double[] exams using length numExams
    double[] exams = new double[MAX_STUDENTS]];

    // declare Double[] quizzes using length numQuizzes
    double[] quizzes = new double[MAX_STUDENTS]];

    // declare Double[] HW using length numHW
    double[] hw = new double[MAX_STUDENTS]];

Comment: By doing that I get the error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at GradeCalcArryas.main(GradeCalcArryas.java:168)`